# How to find out if a table can be deleted in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For, one of my projects, I have to find out if "Deletes Occurred" in the tables provided in the database. I'm not exactly sure what it means by deleted occurred? It says, check if the tables can be deleted or not. And it asks for "Yes or No" answer. Any Help?

USING SQLPRO for MSSQL

Comment: For this one it would be best to ask whoever gave you the requirements for your project.  There's really no way for us to properly answer without seeing the complete requirements, and even then it's possible that we'd have the same question as you.

Comment: To be pedantic the only possible answer is NO because tables are not deleted. Rows are deleted, tables are dropped. :) I would go back and ask your professor for clarification because from what you posted it doesn't much sense at all.

Comment: Well, if `BEGIN TRANSACTION; DROP TABLE [x]; ROLLBACK;` does *not* produce an error, the table is droppable... but since it *actually drops the table* (albeit with an undo afterward) that's not the sort of thing you usually check. Are you sure the question isn't about verifying that rows can't be deleted because foreign key constraints should prevent it, or something like that? Does it ask you to perform some actual physical action for verification, or is it a theory question as to what *should* happen in a particular situation?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server I would check if the table exists

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL
```

and then see if that table has any foreign keys pointing at it...

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```